# How can I create a dependency graph from a text file?

Tags: python-2.7, text-files, directed-graph, dependency-graph

Lets say I have a text file with the following data:

```
Form1 | L3 | depends on L4 and L5
Form1 | L4 | no dependence 
Form1 | L5 | depends on L6
Form1 | L7 | no dependence
```

What I would like to do is output a directed graph (where direction means "depends on"). In this example, we would have a graph with 2 components, one being a single vertex labelled "L7", and the other being 4 vertices connected in series (a 4-path), with arrows in the obvious directions.

I'm using Python 2.7 on a mac. I'm also very new to programming, but very skilled in mathematics (if that makes a difference).

Answer (score 1):

One easy way would be to convert your input text file format to the Graphviz "dot" file format.  Here's an example of someone writing a dot file using Python with no external libraries: [How can python write a dot file for GraphViz asking for some edges to be colored red?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23734030/how-can-python-write-a-dot-file-for-graphviz-asking-for-some-edges-to-be-colored)

And there's PyDot which you could use to do the same thing: https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot

Once you have a "dot" file,  you can  turn it into an actual image using Graphviz (a separate program): http://www.graphviz.org/

Comment: `pydot` has the capability to export images directly.